# ¿Input de tipo file que seleccione automaticamente archivos?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un **input** de tipo **file** y con la propiedad **multiple**, es decir puedo seleccionar varios archivos. En concreto necesito enviar al servidor tres tipos de archivos:

```
 1. archivo.shp
 2. archivo.shx
 3. archivo.dbf
```

Me gustaría que en el menú para elegir archivos del input al seleccionar cualquiera de los archivos anteriores automáticamente seleccione los demás (si existen). Es decir si yo selecciono `archivo.shp`, me seleccione además `archivo.shx`  y `archivo.dbf` si existen en el mismo path que archivo.shp.

¿Cómo podría implementar algo así con JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun la documentación esto no se puede hacer por seguridad

> The file input type creates a field through which users can upload files from their local computer or network. The **VALUE** attribute specifies the name of the initial file, but it is typically ignored by browsers as a security precaution.
>
> Los input de tipo File es un punto de entrada para que el usuario pueda subir archivos desde su ordenador local o de red. El **VALOR** del atributo especifica el nombre del archivo inicial, pero normalmente es ignorado por los navegador por medida de seguridad.

Comment: Vaya... que decepción! =( Aceptaré la respuesta en 3 min.

Comment: Para que necesitas que suba otros archivos si selecciona uno de los 3? Por que no seleccionar los 3?

Comment: Para evitar pulsar en los 3, porque en realidad son tres archivos dependientes unos de otros. En ciertos softwares que leen este tipo de archivos al seleccionar el `.shp` cogen los demás archivos si existen (si no da error) XD Y quería probar algo parecido para subir estos archivos al server. Saludos!

Comment: Como son dependientes unos con otros, puedes hacer que el usuario sea forzado a subir los 3 juntos o el envio no se hace correcto, suerte con eso!

Comment: Ya implementé eso tanto del lado del cliente como del servidor. Pero me hubiera gustado finalizar con eso. No pasa nada! Saludos y gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

1. deberias verificar si el archivo existe!

> ```
> function fileExists(path) {
>   try {
>     if(fs.accessSync('/nombre del archivo')) {
>       return true;
>     }
>   } catch (e) {
>     return false;
>   }
> }
> ```

luego cambiar el formato de tu archivo  de .shp a .shx y .dbf

y utilizar la funcion de arriba para verificar si existe esos archivos con diferente formato.

Comment: Eso ya lo hago en el lado del servidor. Me refiero del lado del cliente. Al seleccionar el archivo archivo.shp me seleccione los otros dos archivos que faltan directamente.